# Error while installing docker in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting this error while installing Docker CE on Ubuntu 16.04 :

```
 >  docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine    Loaded:
    > loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset:
    > enabled)    Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code)
    > since Wed 2018-05-23 17:49:42 IST; 3ms ago
    >      Docs: https://docs.docker.com   Process: 9708 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 
    > Main PID: 9708 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    > 
    > May 23 17:49:42 HMECD001209 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker
    > Application Container Engine. May 23 17:49:42 HMECD001209 systemd[1]:
    > docker.service: Unit entered failed state. May 23 17:49:42 HMECD001209
    > systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. dpkg:
    > error processing package docker-ce (--configure):  subprocess
    > installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    > Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ... Processing
    > triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ... Processing triggers for
    > ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ... Errors were encountered while processing: 
    > docker-ce E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
add this ,
{
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
Edit this ,
sudo nano /etc/default/docker
add this  . DOCKER_OPTS="-s overlay"
then sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker ,it will work .

Comment: Just curious. From where did you get the soluton ?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to install docker ce on ubuntu as per docker official installation guide:

1. Install using the repository
2. INSTALL DOCKER CE
3. Install from a package

Ref. https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

**Suggestion:** Prefer second to install docker ce on Ubuntu easily, Just make sure you install latest stable version instead of edge until you have a specific requirement for edge. **Don't forget to read official installation guide before start.**